# Running two .withSuccessHandler() on body onload

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following GAS to load values to an array, which then displays in a dropdown input HTML UI.

**GAS**

```
function getProjectList() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    var list  = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 2).getValues();
    var values  = list.toString().split(",");
    return values;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="addProjectList();"> 
    <input list="ProjectDropdownList" name="projectList" placeholder="Choose Value" required>
        <datalist id="ProjectDropdownList">
        </datalist>
    <input list="ActivityDropdownList" name="activityList" placeholder="Choose Value" required>
        <datalist id="ActivityDropdownList">
        </datalist>
</body>

<script>
function addProjectList() {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(addProjectListValues)
    .getProjectList();
}

function addProjectListValues(values) {
  var list = document.getElementById('ProjectDropdownList');   
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = values[i];
    list.appendChild(option);
  }
}

function onFailure(err) {
  alert('There was an error!' + err.message);
}
</script>
```

I want to add another dropdown, so I add the following to GAS

```
function getActivityList() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    var list  = sheet.getRange(4, 1, 2).getValues();
    var values  = list.toString().split(",");
    return values;
}
```

and this to the HTML

```
    <input list="ActivityDropdownList" name="activityList" placeholder="Choose Value" required>
        <datalist id="ActivityDropdownList">
        </datalist>
```

---

My question is, how do I correctly `getActivityList()` into the input `activityList`?

I thought that I could duplicate the HTML JS, for example

```
function addActivityList() {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(addActivityListValues)
    .getActivityList();
}

function addActivityListValues(values) {
  var list = document.getElementById('ActivityDropdownList');   
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = values[i];
    list.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

with the body tag being `onload="addProjectList();addActivityList();"` but this does not load any values to the second dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your script, I thought that in your case, `getProjectList()` and `getActivityList()` can be merged. By this, I think that your goal can be achieved by one request of `google.script.run`. When your script is modified it becomes as follows.

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function getLists() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 5).getValues().flat();
  return [values.slice(0, 2), values.slice(3, 5)];
}
```

- I merged `getProjectList()` and `getActivityList()` as `getLists()`.
- From your script, I understood that you want to retrieve the values from cells "A1:A2" and "A4:A5" in the 1st tab of Google Spreadsheet.

#### HTML & Javascript side:

In this case, please modify `addProjectList()` and `addProjectListValues()` as follows.

```
function addProjectList() {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(addProjectListValues)
    .getLists();  // Modified
}

function addProjectListValues([values1, values2]) {
  var list = document.getElementById('ProjectDropdownList');   
  for (var i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = values1[i];
    list.appendChild(option);
  }

  var list = document.getElementById('ActivityDropdownList');   
  for (var i = 0; i < values2.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = values2[i];
    list.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I changed the GAS slightly to pick up a different range, like this `var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 5).getValues();` `var values2 = sheet.getRange(1, 4, 2).getValues();` `return [values, values2];` which works exactly how I need it.